# Pings pinging too many times

Tags: feature-request, chat, ping

In our glorious chat system (may it live forever!), I have noticed a grain of sand in the pearly gear system.  This grain of sand is that when a message with a ping is sent, it pings (fine and well).  Then, when the sender edits the message, it pings again.  Then, when they edit it again, it pings again (unsurprising, at this point).  99.99% of the time, these edits are adjusting typos, obscuring profanity, or doing some other minor edit.  I am wondering if this only bothers me, or if other people have noticed it too?  It is definitely not a make-or-break problem, but it would be nice if it was changed so we only get pinged the first time, and if there are substantial changes, the user can just delete the message and send a new one.

Comment: I asked about this in regard to the [specific scenario of quick edits](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/77?m=232136#232136) back in the day, but it never got any traction.

Comment: @TimStone Yes, I'm afraid it is a duplicate, sorry. I voted to close it.

Comment: It's okay, I'm [sympathetic to the issue](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/messages/419078/history)!

Comment: Boy, what a pain.